# SSRS How to return column name of the column which have max value

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table with only column head and 1 row like below

```
>>> table                   
Out[1]: 
   A_Spd1  A_Spd2  A_Spd3  B_Spd1  B_Spd2  B_Spd3  C_Spd1  C_Spd2
      10       5       7       2       4       8       6       2
```

Is there anyway I can do comparison between column and return column with max value ?

For example: A_spd1=10, B_spd1=2, C_spd1=9 --> The function should return name "A_spd1"

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

There maybe be a much more elegant way to do this but this is straight forward. The first part just recreates your data..

```
--re-create your sample table
DECLARE @t TABLE(A_Spd1 int, A_Spd2 int, A_Spd3 int, B_Spd1 int, B_Spd2 int, B_Spd3 int, C_Spd1 int, C_Spd2 int, C_Spd3 int)
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 10,5,7,2,4,8,9,2,6

-- now do the query
-- first unpivot the data so we have 2 columns, colName and colValue
;WITH 
    UnPivTable as (
        SELECT * FROM @t
            UNPIVOT (
                    ColValue FOR ColName IN ([A_Spd1], [A_Spd2], [A_Spd3], [B_Spd1], [B_Spd2], [B_Spd3], [C_Spd1], [C_Spd2], [C_Spd3])
            ) AS U
    )
-- now just select all records where the colValue equals the MAX colValue
SELECT * from UnPivTable 
    WHERE ColValue = (SELECT MAX(ColValue) FROM UnPivTable)
```

This answer assumes that the column names are always the same.
It also assumes that two columns can contain the same highest number, in this case both column names are returned.